# pyglet does not allow to draw sprites with just a region of a image?

Tags: python, pyglet

Question is simple.

Trying to make simple 2d rogue-like with single texture for map (ascii table)

Seems like pyglet does not allow to draw sprites with just a region of a its image.
For doing so i need to implement my own Sprite | Batch?

Comment: [Image sequences and atlases](https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/programming_guide/image.html#image-sequences-and-atlases) might point you in the right direction.

Comment: ‍♂️ how do i missed that? thanks sir!